# Function to get data type of class member

Tags: java

I want a function which accepts the class member name and returns its type.

For e.g.

there is a class A

```
class A {
    private String fieldOne;
    private String fieldTwo;
    private Integer fieldThree;
    private Integer fieldFour;

}
```

I need to write a function which accepts one of the above fileds name and returns its corresponding data type. like if I pass "fieldFour" it should return Integer as type. How can I write such a function. Thank you.

Comment: Just call `obj.getClass()`?

Comment: How? If I am just having the name of the field, then how can I call obj.getClass()?? Thank you

Comment: You need to use reflection

Comment: Ah, ok, you only have the name of the field - I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got to use reflection. E.g.

```
A.class.getDeclaredField("fieldOne").getType()
```

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Stef. But how do I make it work for private members

Comment: Hi, please use getDeclaredField instead. This way you will get all fields. I edited my post.

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Stef